# Deserialisation issue - java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, ioexception, corruption

I'm writing a java file-transfer app, and i have some troubles with deserialisation myself-defined class Message from Datagramms.

Other topics at StackOverflow has similar issues, but i didn't found something helpful from there, so i'm sorry in advance if i missed it.

so, class Message is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int segmentID;
    private byte[] packet;
    private int bytesToWrite;

    public Message(){
        segmentID = -1;
    }

    public Message(int segmentID, byte[] packet, int bytesToWrite) {
        this.segmentID = segmentID;
        this.packet = packet;
        this.bytesToWrite = bytesToWrite;
    }

    public int getBytesToWrite() {
        return bytesToWrite;
    }

    public int getSegmentID() {
        return segmentID;
    }

    public byte[] getPacket() {
        return packet;
    }
}
```

nothing special.
i serialise it with

```
public byte[] serialize(Message obj) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
    objectStream.flush();
    objectStream.writeObject(obj);
    objectStream.flush();
    return byteStream.toByteArray();
}
```

and, actually, send it through datagram

```
msg = new byte[512];
int bytesRead;
bytesRead = fileReader.read(msg);//fileReader is FileInputStream
Message message = new Message(segmentID, msg, bytesRead);
byte[] test = serialize(message);
datagramSocket.send(new DatagramPacket(test, test.length, 
    datagramSocket.getInetAddress(), datagramSocket.getPort()));
```

I recieve it from other place by

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.recieve(recievedPacket); //it's already connected by init packet
receiveMSG = (Message) deserialize(receivedPacket.getData(), 
    receivedPacket.getOffset(), receivedPacket.getLength());
```

where (try/catch blocks are deleted here)

```
private Object deserialize(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)
{
    ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes, offset, length);
    ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(byteStream));
    Object tmpMsg = new Object();
        tmpMsg = objectStream.readObject();//here catches the EOFException
    return tmpMsg;
}
```

why it can be? i did it according instructions at http://goo.gl/Rq1rMm
where and what i did wrong?
i checked that initial messages passes (i have them, but here is only a little piece of my code) and datagram in receive is not null. Moreover, sent and received datagrams has equal length.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put a `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` on your Message class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> receiveMSG = (Message) deserialize(receivedPacket.getData());

You need to change this to

```
receiveMSG = (Message) deserialize(receivedPacket.getData(), receivedPacket.getOffset(), receivedPacket.getLength);
```

and adjust your 'deserialise()' method accordingly, to accept 'offset' and 'length' parameters, and to use them when constructing the ByteArrayInputStream.

**EDIT** The code you posted doesn't compile: the expression that constructs the outgoing datagram packet is incorrect. It should be

```
new DatagramPacket(test, test.length, datagramSocket.getInetAddress(), datagramSocket.getPort())
```

I have no idea what `packetOverhead` is supposed to be, but you don't need it.

NB You don't need to create a `new Message()` the line before you call `readObject().`

Comment: Thank You for your attention, but i don't know if it works, because there is different error now - java.io.EOFException. well, i'll try to google it. Thank You again.

Comment: That's progress. It now means you're trying to read an object that isn't there, or that your receiving byte array was too small. Trace the outgoing and incoming lengths. You should certainly increase 512 to at least 534.

Comment: i wonder, why exactly 534 (and yeah, it's not working)?.. well, ok, thanks for navigating)

Comment: Somewhere in the TCP/IP RFCs the magic number 576 appears as the threshold below which routers may not fragment IP packets. Taking out overhead and some fudge factor, 534 is generally accepted as the maximum possible datagram size for UDP across the Internet. If your sender and receiver are running in the same LAN segment you can go up to at least 8192 if the socket send and receive buffers at both ends, and the application buffers like your byte[] arrays, are large enough.

Comment: found that sended datagram packet has buf = byte[641], while recieved has buf = byte[618]. the message that i send is only 12 bytes, but anyway - can THIS cause that exception?.. well, the place of corruption finally located.

Comment: The message that you send is a serialized stream. It contains a lot more than 12 bytes, and you've just proved it. If you needed 641 bytes at the sender you need 641 at the receiver. I would change the receive buffer to at least 8192. See also my edit above.

Comment: well, ok. anyway, the size of buffer has no effect on EOF-exception. Is there another way to pull an object from stream? I think, there is some problem with reconstructing object from objectstream. The buffer of sended and received datagrams seemed to be equal. Thank You very much for your attention!

Comment: Your code works for me with all the corrections I have noted. Have you really applied them all?

Comment: ehm.. well, i misunderstood something then. would You be so glad to give me some code that You made to ensure that i did that corrections right?

Comment: I suggest you edit your current code into your question.

Comment: That code still doesn't compile. 'new DatagramPacket(Message, ...)' doesn't exist. The first argument is a 'byte[]'. See my **EDIT** above.

Comment: i really sorry, i forgot to refactor a little bit - there is no mistake, i copypasted this string from method `send(byte[] message, int length)`, where `message` is `test` etc.

Comment: That doesn't compile either. I want to see your ***actual code,*** edited into your question. Copy and paste. Not what you *think* it is. If you were right about everything here you wouldn't have a problem, and you wouldn't be asking a question.

Comment: omg. i am a blind mole. just did a code without method calls... and it totally works! ok, it seems to be a mistake just in my method call, but it is already easier to find. thank You very-very much for being so patient with me!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have received all of the bytes for the serialized objects?  A DatagramSocket uses UDP under the hood.  Are you sure that all of the packets have arrived?

Also, is it really a good idea to use UDP for transferring a serialized object?  This is one case where TCP would seem to be more approriate.  UDP does not guarantee delivery or delivery order which could easily cause a corrupted stream.

You should also really put a `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` on your Message class.

Comment: well, i send 1 packet, and it is already "corrupted"... Thank You, i'll try

Comment: about UDP - i have to use it, it's a kind of task

Comment: oh, i just tried to serialize and deserialize a message in one block and compare result with source... well, it's not equal, so i think this is some bad code in func "deserialisation()".

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection.